My Ubuntu machine keeps failing to install Wine
So I decided to install Wine, It told me to install the i386 architecture, this error keeps popping up


When asking, please show us the actual commands you ran. Ideally as text, not as a screenshot we cannot copy from. Especially not a blurry one that doesn't show the entire command.

You didn't run the command as root. You ran several commands, connected with &&. Those are still separate commands and each of the apt-get commands need sudo. You should have run (obviously, change the ... to the actual commands in your screenshot, I just don't want to laboriously copy them):
sudo dpkg ... && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ...

